# Will using Entity Framework be a good choice for databases containing tables with 80k-100k records?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, entity-framework, design-patterns, visual-studio-2010

I am working with **VS 2010, Entity framework, SQl-Server 2005, ASP.Net web forms**. Currently, I am working on the Data access layer library which soon will be a web service, using Entity Framework collaboration with different design patterns like repository pattern and some best practices that posts in different blogs. I am also test each repository using the **Unit testing** project. Thumbs up! Working fine.

The thing I am worried about is, will I benefit from using Entity Framework when retrieving data from tables containing 80-100k records?

Thanks

Comment: There's a spirited discussion on EF scalability here: http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-ado-net/21570/Entity-Framework-on-large-model

The consensus from various forums seems to be that EF's weaknesses are based on the number of tables in an app, not the size of the tables. But if the number of tables you have is small, replacing EF at a later date shouldn't be hard anyway.

Comment: @SteveCav: # of tables in the *model*, not # of tables in the *app.* An app can have lots of models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go with @SteveCav and @Craig Stuntz comment. I just tried with a table that has more than hundredth of thousands records. It just works fine.